# Computing ranged major axis (RMA) regression in Python

Tags: python, r, statistics, regression

It seems that there is no package that computes a RMA regression in Python, only in R (package called `lmodel2`). I am unfamiliar with R and came across some discussion on importing R packages into Python.

Has anyone worked with RMA regression (a type of Model II Regression) in Python? Or been able to import R packages into Python? If so, how? I had trouble downloading `WinPython` as suggested by other comments, so the simpler the better.

Comment: R is pretty easy to learn, so my advice is just use the R package for it. Consider taking a look at the r-help mailing list, which is very active. See: https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-help Finally, since this is more of a discussion question, it's more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I wasn't even aware of the stats.stackexchange so thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package pylr2 includes reduced major axis regression.

```
from pylr2 import regress2
```

To compute regression type 2:

```
results = regress2(x, y, _method_type_2="reduced major axis")
```

https://github.com/OceanOptics/pylr2